# Translate matlab to python/numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, code-translation

I am looking for an automatic code translator for Matlab to Python.
I downloaded and installed [LiberMate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libermate/) but it is **not** documented anywhere and I wasn't able to make it work.

Has anybody dealt with this kind of challenge before? Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i seems there is no other way than to do the translation manually.
I suggest you have these pages in your browser meanwhile:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/
with:
http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc

and:
[Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)
with:
http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html

Answer (score 9):

I've done it manually. Check [this](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html).

**[EDIT]**

You can also try to call your MATLAB code from Python using [Mlabwrap](https://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net/), a high-level Python to MATLAB bridge that lets MATLAB look like a normal Python library.

For example:

```
from mlabwrap import mlab
mlab.plot([1,2,3], '-o')
```

Comment: yes, i know this page. Thanks but when you have thousands of lines to convert, it takes too much time.

Comment: You can try to call MATLAB from Python. Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Install PyClips

- wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyclips/files/pyclips/pyclips-1.0/pyclips-1.0.7.348.tar.gz/download
- tar zxvf download
- cd pyclips
- ./setup.py install

libreMate

- cd /path/to/libermate-0.4
- ./libermate.py /path/to/*matlabfile*.m

This works for me :-)